# differentiate unordered_map vs map

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

What is the difference between unordered_map and map of C++ STL.
Please explain in terms of complexity and use.

I replace map with unordered_map and I got accepted while earlier i was getting Time limit Exceeded.

And where should we use map and where unordered map

Comment: you could perhap's make the effort of googling the terms, and read by your self.

Answer (score 0):

`std::map` has guaranteed O(log N) complexity for search, insertion and deletion. It uses a comparison operator, and iteration happens in the order defined by that comparison operator.

`std::unordered_map` only guarantees O(N) complexity for search, insertion and deletion, *but* you normally expect it to be O(M), where M is (more or less) the size of an individual key. Assuming keys are small relative to the number of items, it's basically O(1).

Comment: If you consider size of key in std::unordered_map then you should also do that in std::map.  The complexity is O(logN * M) where M is (more or less) the complexity for each comparison.

Comment: @icando: yes and no--at least in a typical case, with a map, you can stop a comparison at the first mismatch between two keys, whereas with an unordered map, your hash has to take the entire key into account every time. From a purist viewpoint, they're both O(M), but more practically, the difference can be quite substantial.